# Specifying itemize with \addtolength

Tags: align, lists, itemize, moderncv

I am writing an additional page to my cover letter and cv, so I am using moderncv. Therefore the style of the itemize is defined by the package. For my additoinal page I want a new itemize style that differs from the one in the cv. In particular I want to create increase the left margin. I tried the following one

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.3cm} 

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\name{Name}{name}
\title{Lebenslauf}                             
\address{...}{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}                   
\email{Mail}  

   %Justification    
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
   {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
  {\@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother   





\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Foo}

\section{Foo2}
\subsection*{FooFoo}

\clearpage

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{10cm}Xp{5cm}@{}}
Lineare Regression & &Sehr gute Kenntnisse \tabularnewline
Logistische Regression    & & Basiskenntnisse \tabularnewline
Regularisierte Regression (LASSO, Ridge, Elastic Net) \begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{0.4cm}
\item Bachelorthesis: \glqq \textit{The Name of the thesis, that goes over two lines. It is too gong.}\grqq{} \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}
\end{itemize}   && Sehr gute Kenntnisse 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The problem now is, that the text in the item is too long and its aligned under the bullet point. It should be aligned under the first word of the item.

Note, that I dont want to use the enumitem package, because it changed the style of all lists.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.3cm}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\name{Name}{name}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{...}{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}
\email{Mail}

   %Justification
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
   {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
  {\@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Foo}

\section{Foo2}
\subsection*{FooFoo}

\clearpage

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{10cm}Xp{5cm}@{}}
Lineare Regression & &Sehr gute Kenntnisse \tabularnewline
Logistische Regression & & Basiskenntnisse \tabularnewline
Regularisierte Regression (LASSO, Ridge, Elastic Net)
\def\itemhook{\addtolength{\leftmargin}{0.4cm}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bachelorthesis: \glqq \textit{The Name of the thesis, that goes over two lines. It is too gong.}\grqq{} \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}
\end{itemize} && Sehr gute Kenntnisse
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, without the space between the bullet point and the text (as in the answer of koleygr)

Comment: Here you are. I only redefined `\itemhook` command from `tweaklist`  which comes with `moderncv`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to use a minipage aligned in top:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.3cm} 

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\name{Name}{name}
\title{Lebenslauf}                             
\address{...}{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}                   
\email{Mail}  

   %Justification    
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
   {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
  {\@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother   


\newsavebox{\mybox}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Foo}

\section{Foo2}
\subsection*{FooFoo}

\clearpage

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{10cm}Xp{5cm}@{}}
Lineare Regression & &Sehr gute Kenntnisse \tabularnewline
Logistische Regression    & & Basiskenntnisse \tabularnewline
Regularisierte Regression (LASSO, Ridge, Elastic Net) \begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{0.4cm}
\savebox\mybox{\hbox{Sehr gute Kenntnisse}}
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\itemindent-\wd\mybox-20pt}
Bachelorthesis: \glqq \textit{The Name of the thesis, that goes over two lines. It is too gong.}
\grqq{}\end{minipage} \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}
\end{itemize}   && Sehr gute Kenntnisse
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Forgot the quotes out of minipage but have fixed in the code

Comment: That looks pretty good. Euxaristw polu :D

Comment: Welcome Vala. Parakalw...

Comment: @Vala, now, Bernard's solution is easier and much more professionan.. So, consider accepting that solution. I am just don'dwleting mine because it could be a simple fix in similar (but not this) case(s).